# Every time getting positive result while predicting from svm

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

I train svm using surf and bow , and now wher i predict the image it always return me 1 , even when i go for negative image it return me 1 as output

Here is Parameters for svm :

```
CvSVMParams Params;
Params.svm_type=CvSVM::C_SVC;
Params.kernel_type=CvSVM::LINEAR;
Params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
Params.gamma=3;
CvSVM svm;
svm.train(training_mat,labels,cv::Mat(),cv::Mat(),Params);
```

and here is my code for prediction :

```
predict_img = cvLoadImage("ss.jpg",0);
detector.detect(predict_img, keypoint2);
RetainBestKeypoints(keypoint2, 20);
dextract.compute( predict_img, keypoint2, descriptors_2);
Mat my_img_3 = descriptors_2.reshape(1,1);
float response = svm.predict(my_img_3);
cout<<response;
```

Here is intializatio :

```
BOWImgDescriptorExtractor dextract(extractor,matcher);
SurfFeatureDetector detector(500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether you set big enough `C` (I don't see it in your code so it should be set to 1000 according to [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html)) value to force a reasonable model, you should try many values, for many actual problems one have to even use `C` of magnitude of `10^10`. With too small `C`, SVM will simply look for a hyperplane which has a small norm, without really paying attention to correct classification. It is accessible through `Cvalue` parameter in opencv implementation.

```
Params.gamma=3;
```

Even though it does not cause an error - you do not need to set the `gamma` value, as it is not used in the linear kernel, it is required **only** for the RBF kernel.

You should also make sure, that you are training similar amount of positive and negative samples (or use some class-weighting technique), as it could also lead to "trivial" model.

Comment: Yes i am using same amount of positive and negative images , but i train them through different directories , different directory for positive images and different for negative , i didn't understand your concept about `C`

Comment: One of the most important parameters of the SVM model is `C`, the amount of "punishment" for missclassification. It should be set up in the model params: `Cvalue – Parameter C of a SVM optimization problem (C_SVC / EPS_SVR / NU_SVR).`  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html, by default it is set to `C=1000` which may be rows of magnitude to small

Comment: @lijlot you asking about this : `CvParamGrid CvSVM = get_default_grid(CvSVM::C);` but it give me error on `get_default_grid(CvSVM::C)` is not defined

Comment: I'm talking about `Cvalue` of the `Params` object

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer that already has been provided, you will invariably end up asking another question in the future on how to improve your SVM classification performance, that is, set the model parameters correctly.

Towards that goal, you should also investigate the grid search provided by CvParamGrid.

Best

Comment: Should i need to train the data when i am predicting it ? or is there any functionality like this

Comment: The search for parameters needs to be done during the learning step, before predicting.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "get vector support". Are you referring to something specific?

Comment: yes , i read it from opencv documentation of svm , `int c = SVM.get_support_vector_count();` like this

Comment: Oh I now understand. This is used to get the number of support vectors for SVM. You need this to perform SVM computations. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is what am asking , what do you mean by svm computation